# Cannot create the ad video on facebook Marketing API

Tags: ruby, facebook, facebook-marketing-api

I am trying to create a video ad through Facebook Marketing API. And I stuck on uploading the video.

When I am doing the next:

```
ad_video = ad_account.advideos.create(
  name:         'Tests video 1',
  source:       File.expand_path('../file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4') 
)
```

I am getting this response:

```
FacebookAds::ClientError: Service temporarily unavailable: Error Uploading Video
```

Also, I was trying to make it with URL:

```
ad_video = ad_account.advideos.create(
  name:                    'Tests video 1',
  title:                   'Test',
  description:             'Test',
  file_url:                'https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4'
)
```

No luck, same answer:

```
FacebookAds::ClientError: Service temporarily unavailable: Error Uploading Video
```

Please help, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way with php

```
function video_creat($token,$act_id,$video_url){
try {
    $fb=fbconngrap(); $response = $fb->post(
'/'.$act_id.'/advideos',
array (
  'file_url' => $video_url,
),$token);} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();exit;}catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();exit;}$graphNode = $response>getGraphNode();}
```

Comment: It's not an idea to switch the programming language for just fixing this issue :)

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with php.(

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry. This is a second of my example. Looks like it's exactly what your code does